# Divs not moving down

Tags: css

In this page http://opensourceeducation.in i want to move the left divs one below another instead of side by side. The code below is used to create them. Most of my attemps interfered with the facebook or twitter feeds on the right.

```
while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))

{
echo'
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="float:left;position:relative;display:inline;">

<div class="thumbnail">

    <div class="caption">

    <h3 class="captionhead">'.$row['TITLE'].'</h3>

    <p class="description">'.$row['Data'].'</p></div>

<div style="margin-bottom:auto;margin-top:15em;position:relative;">

<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>&nbsp;Like</a>

 <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>&nbsp;Dislike</a>
 &nbsp;<a href="downloader.php?id='.$row['vdo_code'].'" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>

 &nbsp;<a class="btn btn-success" href="player.php?id='.$row['vdo_code'].'" > PlaY </a></div>

 </div>

 </div>
';

}
```

**UPDATE**
Removed the float:left and display:inline
Still its same.

Also tried with col-md-12 col-md-12 but the facebookfeed is moving down till the last div

Comment: wowowowo...please post the browser rendered output...that would be easy to find bug!! :)

Comment: You're outputting inline css setting float:left; and display:inline; have a look at what these attributes do, and try removing them, and setting a sepcific div width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change class to `col-sm-12 col-md-12` from `col-sm-6 col-md-4`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of `float:left;` and `display:inline;` going on. Removing these will have each div starting on a new line, underneath the previous one

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WS3Mj/1/) for examples of how float and inline work with divs.

Comment: Okay. I just added up all the suggesstions and it is working. :D
 <div class="col-md-12">

This is my final code.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `float:left;` and `display:inline;` in the styling of your first div, that should help.

You should also consider using a separate style sheet, rather than inline styles.